# Simplify google sheet formula "SUM / INDEX / MATCH"

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to use google sheet to create a roster formula, to sum up the duty hour per week using INDEX/MATCH/SUM.

But it's too long, is there any way to simplify the formula?
Also, I realize "MATCH" cannot recognize blank cell (N20), can that be fixed too?

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX($O$12:$O$20,MATCH(D17,$N$12:$N$20,0)),INDEX($O$12:$O$20,MATCH(E17,$N$12:$N$20,0)),INDEX($O$12:$O$20,AND(F17,$N$12:$N$20,0)),INDEX($O$12:$O$20,MATCH(G17,$N$12:$N$20,0)),INDEX($O$12:$O$20,MATCH(H17,$N$12:$N$20,0)),INDEX($O$12:$O$20,MATCH(I17,$N$12:$N$20,0)),INDEX($O$12:$O$20,MATCH(J17,$N$12:$N$20,0))),"Err")
```

[image: Roster]

[image: Sum up formula]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(UPPER(B6:H14), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, L1:L10)&"$",
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(UPPER(B6:H14), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, L1:L10)&"$"), L1:M10, 2*
 SIGN(ROW(A6:A14)), 0)&""), UPPER(B6:H14))*1, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B:H))^0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Franco, since your post says your end goal is to "sum up the duty hour per week," I take that to mean all you need in the end is a single number.

Try this (which will give you total hours for your block that runs B6:H22:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF(B6:H22,$L$1:$L$8)*$M$1:$M$8))
```

If you need to see the breakdown per code, you can use this:

```
=ArrayFormula({$L$1:$L$8,COUNTIF(B6:H22,$L$1:$L$8)*$M$1:$M$8})
```

Just replace "B6:H22" with the reference of each calendar block to get the sum or the breakdown for other weeks.

Comment: Hi Erik, since I would like to calculate the weekly hr for each staff, I changed your formula to B6:H6 and that's work too. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it was not immediately clear to me what your setup is or what you are trying to accomplish. I'm glad you were able to modify the formulas to suit your actual need.